# Why textView do not accommodate text kept inside it?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uitextview

I have a plain textView and text inside it. With boundingRect i determine size based on text property of UITextView. Then i apply it to the size of my cell of collectionView. But text do not lay completely inside textView.[image] but if i add to the width of the retrieved size 10 points everything works ok [image]
Maybe i did not take something into account when was applying size to the cell?

Here i created my textView inside cell Class:

```
class experimentalCell: BaseCellInAppStoreFolder {
 lazy var familySharingView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.text = "Family Sharing"
        tv.textAlignment = .right
        tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        tv.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin
          let dummySize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: self.frame.height - 16)
        let rect = tv.text?.boundingRect(with: dummySize, options: options, context: nil)

        tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
        return tv
    }()
override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()
    addSubview(textView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: textView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: textView)
}
}
```

Then I applied size obtained form rect property to size of my cell.

Comment: There might be some kind of padding in the textview

Comment: tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0) what else there might be? please if you know give me a clue

Comment: i got it! I lost my attention on lineFragmentPadding property!